# I need visual examples of topological concepts

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to understand basic concepts of topology, unfortunately I'm a very visual person, and as much documentation there is on how to come up with closed/open/clopen/etc. There are very few visual examples (using actual sets of integers, shapes, etc). So it's very hard for me to understand. Not everyone learns through text or mathematical definitions, so I figured this could help other people that have the same difficulties I have. Thanks for your help!

Can anyone get an example of a topology over a set.

I need one for a topology over a set, an open set, closed set, and clopen set. It needs to be something real. Like, say a set contained numbers { 1,2,3,4 }

It doesn't have to be that set, but it has to be a actual set of something (numbers, letters, geometric shapes), no labels (set X is the union of set Y and set Z), etc.

Comment: See for instance *A Little Example* in http://bigi.org.uk/2007/11/02/topology-5-topological-spaces/

Comment: So a topology doesn't have to contain a permutation of every element?

Comment: @Xaade: It's not clear to me what you mean. Every set has both the discrete (every point is open) and the indiscrete (only open sets are the whole set and the empty set) topologies. I can't imagine any way "permutation" would be meaningful in these topologies.

Comment: You don't need "variables" to visually explain the difference between an open disk and a closed disk in the plane, and I think that would be a lot more meaningful and helpful than an artificial example of a topology over a finite set. To demonstrate a clopen set you can show a connected component in a disconnected space (like the union of two disks). 

I realize you can't just "draw" a closed vs an open disk and see the difference, but by emphasizing the border differently and some verbal explanation you can make the distinction very clear.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/19152/why-is-a-topology-made-up-of-open-sets might be of some help.

Comment: @Xaade: Nobody I know downvotes because they don't know how to answer, they downvote because they think it's not a good question. Your comment above about "permutation of every element" shows confusion on your part. While *I* didn't downvote, I'll note that your question lacks  motivation (*why* do you "need" this); and is unclear (what does it mean for an example to be "real"? what is a "visual set"?)  Taking the attitude of "if you downvoted me, it must be because you are too dumb to come up with an answer" is unlikely to get you many friends, or many good answers. And there are no variables

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the question is asking, but in Munkres' Topology when he defines a topology (in one of the first chapters after the set theory stuff) he has pictures of different topologies on a set with three points.  It might be useful for you to think of some corresponding topologies for four points and ask someone who knows topology a bit better (or just run through the definition carefully!) to see if they satisfy the conditions to be a topology.

Comment: I didn't ever insinuate that anyone is too dumb to answer. I expressed frustration that no one seems to understand what "an example" means. There are no EXAMPLES anywhere that I could find. I'm sorry if you felt I meant people were too dumb, that's not what I meant.

Comment: @Xaade: And again. I know what "an example" means. I just don't know what **you** think it means, given all the nonsensical or meaningless  or ungrammatical verbiage such as "variables flying around", "something real", "numbers contained {1,2,3,4}". Yelling the word "example" doesn't make what you are saying any clearer.

Comment: @Arturo @Asaf had no problems understanding me.

Comment: @Xaade: Glad you think your doubts have been cleared up, sorry I'm such a blockhead that I cannot help. In any case, keep in mind that writing in all caps is the equivalent of yelling, and that saying things like "I'll assume no one knows how to demonstrate this" after a single hour is not particularly helpful. Good luck.

Comment: @Arturo Yeah I slipped. I'm cleaning it up though.

Comment: @Xaade: one thing which is totally missing from your question is motivation and background.  The confluence of (i) wanting to know the rudiments of general topology and (ii) being unable/unwilling to read a standard introductory text is somewhat unusual.  You say "Not everyone learns through text or mathematical definitions..." which is true, but at a certain point in their undergraduate career students of mathematics get trained to do just this.  So I gather you're not a student of mathematics in the formal sense.  That's fine, but then...who are you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider the set $X=\{1,2,3\}$.

- We have the *trivial* topology, namely $T=\{\emptyset,\{1,2,3\}\}$.
- We have the *discrete* topology, in which every singleton is open. This produces the topology to be $P(X)=\{\emptyset,\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{2,3\},\{1,2,3\}\}$
- We may have something in between declaring the nonempty open sets to be those containing $1$, and then we have $\{\emptyset,\{1\},\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{1,2,3\}\}$.

Closed sets are those whose complement is open, and clopen sets are those which are open and closed as well.

Note that $X$ is always clopen relatively to $X$ (it might not be if we take a larger set and endow it with a different topology).

In the trivial topology we only have clopen sets, because we only require the minimum from the topology, while the set $\{1,2\}$ is neither open nor closed.

In the discrete topology every subset of $\{1,2,3\}$ is open, therefore every subset is closed. Since every subset is both open and closed, every subset is clopen.

In the last example note that all those that include $1$ are open, so those who do not include $1$ are closed. Since $1$ cannot be in both a set an its complement we have that there are no clopen sets except the empty set and $\{1,2,3\}$.

However it is important to remember that this is all *relative* and clopen, open and closed sets are only in this relationship with a specific topology and space.

**Addendum:** I feel that I should add a very basic explanation about topology.

Suppose we have an underlying set $X$. A topology on $X$ is a collection of subsets which includes the empty set as well $X$ itself. It is closed under unions and finite intersections.

The sets which are in the topology are called *open*, and their complements are called *closed*. A set which is both open and closed is usually called *clopen*.

Comment: This part I get lost on: "In the discrete topology everything is open, therefore everything is closed and thus everything is clopen."

Comment: Xaade: I had tried to clarify that part a bit.

Comment: @Asaf : So, every member of the topology is automatically open? If it's complement exists, it is also closed. In the discrete case, every member is closed, because every member has their complement in the topology as well. Therefore all members are clopen.

Comment: A set (topologically speaking) is not like a door.  A door is either open, or it is closed; it cannot be both open and closed.  A set can be both open and closed, neither open nor closed...one or the other...etc...  Keep in mind that "not open" is not equivalent to closed, and "not closed" is not equivalent to open. And...its status as closed, open, clopen....etc *is relative* to the topological space with respect to which it is defined.

Comment: @Xaade: By **definition**, the "topology on the set" is the collection of all open sets, so **by definition** an element of $\tau$ is open, and if it is open then it is an element of $\tau$. The complement **always** exists, and **by definition** the complement of an open set is closed (in fact, "closed" *means* "its complement is open"). "Clopen" just means "both open and closed".

Comment: @Amy J.M.: Actually a door CAN be both open and closed: It can be ajar:-)

Comment: @Mike: Actually, I count "ajar" as "open" :-)  Thanks for the humor.

Comment: @Amy J.M.: If a 2-year-old, who cannot reach the door handle, can go through the door, shouldn't the door be considered open?

Answer (score 10):

This picture is from *Topology* , by J. Munkres.

[image: topologies on set with 3 elements]

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for visuals on topology, look no further than Wolfram MathWorld:
[image: topological drawings]

The blood types (O+, AB+, etc) form a topology under the power set topology: http://tumblr.com/xp12cy25v0. [image: blood types topology]

That's a visual for the power set topology on {1,2,3}. And as Asaf said, you can topologise {1,2,3} with the trivial topology or something else (as long as your $\cup$s and $\cap$s commute), though the above visual wouldn't work (nor would the logic).

Also @Xaan, a tip: you might want to be more polite, since people are helping you here for free.

Answer (score 1):

Knowledge comes in the doing. So, in order to understand topological definitions, it would be wise to study a specific real-world example, and a great real-world example is the celebrated topological proof (by Furstenberg/פורסטנברג) of the infinitude of primes. Here’s the [Wikipedia article about it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furstenberg%27s_proof_of_the_infinitude_of_primes).

Also, I realize that it is somewhat tangential to the thrust of your question, but I feel I should mention the classic book “Mathematical Snapshots” by Hugo Steinhaus. Here’s a review from the Amazon site:

> Numerous photographs and diagrams help explain and illustrate mathematical phenomena in this series of thought-provoking expositions. Ranging from simple puzzles and games to more advanced problems, topics include the psychology of lottery players, the arrangement of chromosomes in a human cell, new and larger prime numbers, the fair division of a cake, how to find the shortest possible way to link a dozen locations by rail, and many other absorbing conundrums. A fascinating glimpse into the world of numbers and their uses. 1969 edition. 391 black-and-white illus.

Regards,
Mike Jones